# Visual Studio 2015 can't find header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I I realize that this problem has been asked before, but I cannot seem to apply the answer in my version of Visual Studio. It will only recognize header files I copy to the project directory.

VS can't find the file 'jni.h':

[image]

The header file is located in following directory:
[image]

The directory is added to the 'Include directories' option:
[image: the file is clearly there]

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You just cut off the buttons at the top, by I guess the left one doesn't say `Active`, in which case you set the directories for some other configuration.

Comment: Can u add another dummy include folder with also a dummy header file and check if its working or not? It seems like your path is correct but maybe on windows you might need slashes other way around and/or doubled.

Comment: @BoPersson - that was it, thank you.